# Операции в java, хитрый вопрос

Tags: java

не могу сам разобраться в какой последовательности происходят вычисления, т.е. последовательность выполнения операций я знаю, а как они работают в конкретно этом случае - не понятно 
дано:

```
int x,y,z; 
x=y=z=1; // тут все ясно сначала 1 равен z потом y потом x, в результате все переменные 
//равны единице, а вот тут не ясно:
//для тех же переменных со значениями 1

x+=y-=z/=x+2;
System.out.println(" x="+x);
System.out.println(" y="+y);
System.out.println(" z="+z);
//в консоль вышло:
x=2
y=1
z=0

// почему y=1 z=0 не понимаю
// по приоритетам операций выполняется сначало
//сложение + , а потом += -= /=
// но тут не понятно, что и за чем, хотелось бы ,чтобы кто-нибудь расписал 
// полную последовательность выполнения операций
```

Answer (score 8):

Вы забыли о том, что присваивание правоассоциативно, и имеет меньший приоритет, чем арифметические операции. Модифицированное присваивание (`+=` и т. п.) имеет такой же приоритет, как и простое присваивание.

С учётом этого, выражение `x+=y-=z/=x+2;` можно записать так:

x += (y -= (z /= (x + 2)));

Последовательность операций такова:

1. Вычисляем `x + 2`, получаем 3
2. Делим `z` на результат п. 1, получаем 0, результат записываем в `z`, значение подвыражения в средних скобках также 0.
3. Вычитаем из `y` результат п. 2, получаем 1, результат записываем в `y`, значение подвыражения во внешних скобках 1.
4. Прибавляем к `x` результат п. 3, получаем 2, результат записываем в `x`. Значение подвыражения 2, но мы его не используем.

Всё.